# SD card has to be inserted multiple times before partitions are detected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, mount, sd-card

When I insert a SD card on the slot for the SD card, the OS detects that a disk has been inserted, however the partitions are not listed so I cannot mount the card to access the partitions. I have to insert the SD card multiple times before the partitions are detected.

This happens with all SD cards that I have tested (at least 10 different ones) and with different SD adapters.

This is the output of dmesg when I insert the SD card in the slot and the partitions are not found:

```
[719887.160646] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 121 using xhci_hcd
[719887.310469] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6366
[719887.310472] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[719887.310473] usb 1-4: Product: Flash Card Reader/Writer
[719887.310475] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[719887.310476] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 058F63666485
[719887.311379] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[719887.311506] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-4:1.0
[719888.329456] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Multiple Card  Reader     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[719888.329714] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
```

This is when the partitions are found:

```
[720057.687773] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 122 using xhci_hcd
[720057.837576] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6366
[720057.837578] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[720057.837579] usb 1-4: Product: Flash Card Reader/Writer
[720057.837581] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[720057.837582] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 058F63666485
[720057.838184] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[720057.838295] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-4:1.0
[720058.848648] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Multiple Card  Reader     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[720058.848919] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[720059.385156] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 60637184 512-byte logical blocks: (31.0 GB/28.9 GiB)
[720059.387009] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is on
[720059.387011] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 80 00
[720059.388888] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: disabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[720059.395318]  sdc: sdc1
[720059.400132] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Why arent the partitions being recognized? How can I do to make the partitions on the SD card be recognized immediately?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

UPDATE:

I tried reading an SD card with a FCR-MRR and a generic USB reader. I get different results:

FCR-MRR, I can see /dev/sdc but no partitions:

```
[781195.153227] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 37 using xhci_hcd
[781195.308811] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=6200
[781195.308814] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[781195.308815] usb 1-1: Product: Generic USB2.0 card 
[781195.308817] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Silicon Motion, Inc.
[781195.308818] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 12345678901234567890
[781195.309589] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[781195.309686] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[781196.333858] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB  SD Reader   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[781196.334282] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[781196.334941] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Generic USB reader, no /dev/sdc listed:

```
[781244.211748] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 38 using xhci_hcd
[781244.361940] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=1212
[781244.361942] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[781244.361944] usb 1-1: Product: Mass Storage Device
[781244.361945] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Generic
[781244.361946] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 121220160204
[781244.362718] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[781244.362815] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[781245.375268] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[781245.375485] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
```

I also tried on an other PC with Debian with the same results. However if I use a spektra mini card reader I can read all my SD cards with no issues.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: If when inserted the first time, it's not recognised, run `rescan-scsi-bus.sh` and see if it gets picked up. If it still doesn't, wait a few minutes for it to warm up and retry. It does sound like the card is borked. I'm sure `Ubuntu` has the command somewhere in its packages.

Comment: @Bib Just tried rescan-scsi-bus.sh multiple times (more than 30 times). But still partitions are not detected. I can still only see /dev/sdc, but no partitions.

Comment: There could be a problem with the contacts on the machine side.  Perhaps you can try the SD card in a USB reader (temporarily) to see if the issue lies with your reader contacts?  ¡buena suerte!

Comment: I just tried with two different USB readers on two different USB ports with two different SD cards. With one reader  I can see /dev/sdc but no partitions and with the other one I can see movement with dmesg but no /dev/sdc. Nada

Comment: @TomásArturoHerreraCastro Have you tried using a blank SD card and creating the partitions on a problem machine to check if the problem machine then recognizes the partitions more quickly? However [all these readers don't work] and [this reader does work] suggests that the one that does work has a properly supported device driver. Can you find out what chips each reader uses without breaking anything?

Comment: I found this: "Fact is, some memory card readers do not work properly under Linux Mint/Ubuntu." - [SD Card Reader not detecting SD cards](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=384178).

Comment: And you should be using a supported release. Ubuntu 16.04 is out of support since April 2021. You're missing many security updates (the main problem) and the issue with the SD card reader can very well be related to the drivers included in the old kernel you're running now and will never be updated. You can easily test that hypotheses by running a live session of any currently supported Ubuntu release.